# Check if a certain user has tweeted

Tags: twitter, bots

Is it possible to write a script for twitter that checks when the last time a certain user has tweeted?

Preferably using python.

Comment: It's probably irrelavant, which programming language you use. Please check the Twitter API for basic possibilities and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here is how using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI).

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

SCREEN_NAME = 'justinbieber'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'XXXX'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXX'

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,
                 CONSUMER_SECRET,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
r = api.request('statuses/user_timeline', {'screen_name':SCREEN_NAME, 'count':1})

for item in r:
        print(item['created_at'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library for accessing the Twitter API called [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)

More info on the API can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com

An older post but may be relevant: [streaming api with tweepy only returns second last tweet and NOT the immediately last tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083936/streaming-api-with-tweepy-only-returns-second-last-tweet-and-not-the-immediately)